# Continuity of multivariable functions along axes

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I was given the following problem:

> Let $f:D(\subseteq R2) \to R$ be a function and $(a, b) \in D$. If $f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(a, b)$, then show that the functions $f(x, b)$ and $f(a, y)$ are continuous at $x = a$ and at $y = b$ respectively.

This fact seems obvious so it's hard to figure out how to prove it rigorously. My attempt:

$f(x, y)$ is continuous at $(a,b)$ implies that it is continuous in a neighborhood around (a, b). That is, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta$ such that $|f(x, y) - f(a,b)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|(x,y) - (a,b)| < \delta$.

Since the one-dimensional neighbourhood $(x,b)$ such that $|(x,b) -(a,b)| < \delta$ is situated within the above neighbourhood, this implies $f(x, b)$ is continuous at $x=a$. Similarly for the other case.

Is this a rigorous proof?

Comment: You can try proving the contrapositive : If $f(x, b)$ is not continuous at $x = a$ or $f(a, y)$ is not continuous at $y = b$ then $f(x, y)$ is not continuous at $(a, b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $g(y) = (a,y)$. Then you can easily verify that $g$ is a continuous function. Now observe that $f(a,y) = f \circ g$ which is a composition of two consinuous function and therefore is continuous. Similarly, $f(x,b)$ can be shown to be a continuous real function of one real variable.